# Sort SQL Rows with math using JSON data

Tags: mysql, sorting, dynamic

Let's say I have a MySQL database like this (The upvotes and downvotes are JSON arrays of user ids), id is an auto-incrementing integer, and content is text)

```
id  upvotes             downvotes    content
--- ------------------- ------------ --------------
1   [1, 5, 15]          [1]          some text
10  [1, 100, 25]        [3, 9]       other stuff
17  [5, 10, 1110]       [5, 6, 7, 8] also includes
36  [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]     []           metadata stuff
37  [5, 6, 8, 10, 1, 7] [4]          equal count to 36
```

I would like to sort the rows returned by the number of upvotes minus the number of downvotes, then by id when equal, so the ids would be in the order of `36, 37, 1, 10, 17`. Would this be possible in PHP, and how?

(This question is a repost of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527800/sort-sql-rows-with-math-using-column-data-in-php because it works by counting arrays instead of simply getting numbers out of the rows.)

Comment: What is the type of the data stored in the columns upvotes and downvotes?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not have native JSON support, although it appears to be coming.  So, you have to treat these values as strings.  Basically, you want to count the number of elements in each string and sort by the difference.

You can do this by counting commas:

```
order by (length(upvotes) - length(replace(upvotes, ',', '')) ) -
         (length(downvotes) - length(replace(downvotes, ',', '')) )
```

Note:  if you are maintaining the string of each possible vote, perhaps you should also include a counter in the record as well.

Comment: Will this count character length of _only_ commas or _excluding_ commas? If it excludes them, user ids with multiple digits count for more. Just asking, I don't know much about advanced SQL functions like this.

Comment: @Klikini . . . It takes the length of the string and then it subtracts from it the length of the string with no commas.  That has the effect of counting the number of commas in the string.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I haven't had time yet to mess with it this week, so I'll have to try this.